# Checking for File and not Running command till file doesn't exist in batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, while-loop, goto

I'm feeling a bit constrained by batch's limitations and unsure the best way to code some logic. I have a hybrid Batch/VBScript for printing and decided the best way to confirm the VBScript had finished was by utilizing an external file as a placeholder.

The logic is like this:

Batch Script --> Create tmpfile --> Run VBScript

VBScript --> Print Job --> Delete File

That part works, but in my "call script" I have an array of files that I use a `FOR LOOP` to iterate over and print, but I can't figure out how to code the logic `WHILE FILE EXISTS DON'T RUN NEXT PRINT JOB`. I have figured out how to "loop" until the file doesn't exist, but this uses `GoTo` statements and they don't work inside `FOR LOOPS`. I tried using "EXIT /B" which I thought just exits a function, but it just closed the main script all together.

Here is my "call script" which needs some help~

```
::This is a placeholder file to check if VBScript is running
SET File="%TEMP%\jobrunning.txt"
del /F /Q %File%

::Print Each File in Array
for /l %%n in (0,1,%arrsize%) do (
SET FILEPATH="FILEPATH=!file[%%n]!
GoTo file_exists
)

::Is Job Still Running?
:file_exists
   IF EXIST %File% (
       GoTo :file_exists
) ELSE (
ECHO %PFUNC% %FILEPATH%
%PFUNC% %FILEPATH%
EXIT /B
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using `GoTo` w/ `EXIT /B`. `GoTo` just jumps to a `LINELABEL`, and `EXIT /B` exits `PROCESS` IE: The Script. `CALL` opens a `SUBPROCESS` and `EXIT /B` returns to the main `PROCESS` allow further code execution. (It's the same as calling an external script and closing it).

This is what I ended up using to test and just deleted the file manually after each iteration of the array.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion



::This is a placeholder file to check if VBScript is running
SET File="%TEMP%\jobrunning"
del /F /Q %File%

::Set arrsize -1
set  arrsize=4
set  arrayline[0]=1A
set  arrayline[1]=2A
set  arrayline[2]=3A
set  arrayline[3]=4A
set  arrayline[4]=5A

::read it using a FOR /L statement
for /l %%n in (0,1,%arrsize%) do (
copy /y NUL %TEMP%\jobrunning.txt >NUL
TIMEOUT 2
CALL :file_exists
echo !arrayline[%%n]!
)
PAUSE

GoTo :EOF

:Is Job Still Running?
:file_exists
   IF EXIST %File% (
       GoTo :file_exists
) ELSE (
EXIT /B
)
```